# How to convert a char 2D array to int in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, arduino

I have a char 2D array called char newString[][]
I want to convert the 2nd and 3rd rows to integers.
Lets say newString[2]= {1,2} and newString[3]= {2,2]}
I am trying to get int n = 12 and int m = 22 by turning my 2D array into an integer. Because later I want to do m^n  ( m to the power of n).

```
     char newString[32][32];
     int n;
     int m;

  // let newString[2]= {1,2}
  // let newString[3]= {2,2}
  // convert it to an int 

     m = newString[2] - '0'; // I want m = 12
     n = newString[3] - '0';  // n = 22
```

I know that char - '0' will give you an integer if assigned to an integer, but how to assign a 2d array into an integer

I tried using these, but they only work for 1D arrays, any ideas?

Comment: You are looking for [`strtol`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/). What you have tried doesn't even work for 1D arrays, it works for converting a char like `3` to `3`.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what worked and sample input and desired output.

Comment: @Yunnosch I literally showed you my input and desired output. it says I have a 2d array that I want to make into an integer. input is the array newString[2] of value {1,2}. I want to turn it into int n = 12

Comment: You do not provide a MRE. You do not provide the input (i.e. content of `newString` and surely you are not expecting anythign from an uninitialised input array). You do say that you want 12 and 22, but based on the shown code that is not at all clear. And it is not a desired output for provided sample input. Yes, you do state the desired result, but without any foundation and you do not provide the other info I asked for. Even with the recently applied edit (which shows some of what you think you have as input, or what you want as input) it does not actually provide sample input for an MRE.

Comment: Please consider explaining how the shown "input" is related to expecting 12 and 22. For me there is a huge discrepancy. It would get somewhat clearer if you would actually use input with characters which make "12" and "22" but your newly shown code has integers, which would (multiplied by powers of 10 and added) make the desired result, that however is urelated to the rest of the code which attempts to convert characeter repüresentations to digits...

Comment: Really, if you did something successful with a 1D array, then please show a [mre] of that. I bet that code is different in more ways than the dimension of the array. And showing it would also help a lot with all the missing declarations, intialisations, etc. which the current question does not provide (some of it, after the edit...). Please read [ask] and embrace the value of a [mre].

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you! that is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

the function: `strtol()` will not do the desired functionality as there is no trailing NUL byte, so no string to convert.

Suggest:

```
// given
char newString[][] =
{
    { '1', '2'},
    { '2', '2'}
};

// convert to integers
int n = newString[0][0] - '0';
n     = n*10 + (newString[0][1] - '0');


int m = newString[1][0] - '0';
m     = m*10 + (newString[1][1] - '0');

// which results in:
// n contains 12
// m contains 22
```